# How to send messages to the tab after page load in native safari app extension

Tags: javascript, swift, safari-app-extension

In native safari extension,How to call  dispatchMessageToScript after page loaded ,
In chrome we are using " chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(listener);” function in background script and this is giving us tab URL and status with ‘complete’ then we are sending our message to the particular tab.
Please help me out to find an alternate solution for safari app extension

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear and hard to read. But, if you are asking how to wait until the DOM is loaded before executing, then that is exactly what the example in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/injecting_a_script_into_a_webpage) shows, refer to the section 'Execute Your Code After the Webpage Loads'.